# USA keyboard layout keeps getting added on login

Tags: 11.04, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I use the USA International keyboard layout. Every time I log in, the USA layout gets added to my list of layouts, which causes the keyboard layout indicator to be displayed. How can I stop the USA layout from being added?

Additional info: I'm running Natty. Until recently, I had all four layout slots filled. Recently I changed from SCIM to iBus. With this change, I no longer need multiple layouts since iBus better handles my needs. So, I don't want both indicators (iBus and Keyboard layout) showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3355/keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-wont-go-away/3366#3366) solved my problem. While I initially thought that that question dealt with an unrelated issue, it turns out that it actually is the same issue.

To summarize here, the solution is to choose the desired layout on the login screen. Then, the old layout will stop showing up and the keyboard layout indicator will be gone for good.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same problem, only a clean install and selecting the right keyboard during the install worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, a clean install is completely out of the question. It would take far too long to get the system set up again the way I want it.