# the keyboard layout randomly turns off dead keys on boot

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters, dead-keys

I'm using the English (US international with dead keys) keyboard layout and no other layout has been set up.
My problem is that my computer turns the dead keys off seemingly random at boot. To fix this I have to set up another keyboard layout and then switch back to the English (US international with dead keys).

This is quite annoying and I'm hoping someone can shed some light onto the randomness that is my keyboard layout.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome-shell version 3.10.4 and Gnome desktop (Gnome-session) version 3.9.90

Comment: I have been experiencing the same situation, even though this is the only keyboard I have installed, randomly at boot it works, and it doesn't.
It is so so annoying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been looking into this for like one hour, because it has been nuisance for me as well.

**EASY SOLUTION**

The simplest solution I found, but I am not too sure if this is working all the time but it's worth the try as the first solution is when you login in, at the right top corner, you will be able to choose your keyboard, Choose the one you want from the list, after that, next time it will be the remembered (I'm not quiet sure how this works out with multiple users who choose different keyboard layouts).

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Just use it if the Easy Solution did not work.
The other solution that i found is to override gnome-setting with the default system settings,

run this until you get the desired keyboard layout

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active
```

and setxkbmap will tell you those settings

```
$ setxkbmap -query
```

and you will get something like:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
variant:    intl
options:    lv3:ralt_switch
```

So just add the new two following commands to be executed when ubuntu starts up, by adding the them `/etc/rc.local`

Command #1:

```
# prevent gnome from resetting keyboard setting in X
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

Command #2: (based on the information obtained above by `setxkbmap -query`

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model pc105 -layout us -variant intl -option lv3 -option lv3:ralt_switch
```

Sources:

- [Keyboard layout on Ubuntu won't go away!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3355/keyboard-layout-on-ubuntu-wont-go-away/3366#3366)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out tomorrow and let you know if it worked

Comment: There was no need for the second command. setting 'gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false' and then setting it back to active works every time (tried 20 reboots). Thanks for the help.